# How costly is using Factory Pattern in Java

Tags: java, android, performance, oop

Lets assume we have this Adapter/Factory design pattern in our Android project, aiming for the ability to decouple network operations implementation from network operations usage and the ability to switch between different network libraries seamlessly

```
public interface LogInNetworkAdapter {
    void login(String email, String password, OnLoginListener listener);
}

public class LogInNetworkAdapterImpl implements LoginNetworkAdapter {

    @Override
    void login(...) {
        // Retrofit implementation
    }

}

public class LogInNetworkAdapterFactory {

    public enum Type { RETROFIT, OTHER_LIB_1, OTHER_LIB_2 }

    public LogInNetworkAdapter getLogInAdapter(Type type) {

        // return LogInLogInNetworkAdapter Impl depending on type passed
    }


}
```

I want to know what kind of performance (speed, memory) and build (compile, runtime) overhead is associated with this, and can the impact be felt by the user?

How much slower, bigger will an android app be if built this way?

Is it the matter of nanoseconds for class invocations, or is it more expensive than that? How much bigger the footprint of the app be? Is avoiding such implementations for performance's sake a premature optimization, if we do not consider over-engineering an issue in our algorithm for making a decision of what route to take?

Comment: Well... Your user won't feel anything. Invoking a virtual method is waaaaaaay cheaper than data transmitting data over networks. Also, you're asking the question as if you were going to invoke `getLogInAdapter()` very-very-very frequently. Really, why worrying about such things?